# background color don't work

Tags: html, css

Hi I have simple html that I don't know the main content doesn't have a background

please help me

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <header class="p-t10">

        <div id="logo">
            <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="top-banner">
            <a href=""><img src="images/banner-3.gif"/></a>
        </div>


    </header>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Poker Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">divs</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
         <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="center"></div>
          <div class="right"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
        <footer>


        </footer>
    </div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VFRv8/)

Comment: Your question is not clear..please describe elaborately.

Comment: I need the content have a background around the 3 column grid. I don't know why it seems doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the path to the image?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a div `<div class="clear"></div>`, because of the floats, you need to clear the floats to give `main-content` an height (automactly)

```
<div class="main-content">
     ....
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VFRv8/3/)**

Comment: Thanks! This one is what I am looking for. I tried to put a content earlier but it doesn't work. clearing a float is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Only disapointed for all the downvotes without leaving a comment.

Comment: Yeah. Very disappointing. Anyway, I appreciate all the answers. :)

Answer (score -1):

`.main-content` must have a set height since there are floating elements inside it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFRv8/2/

Comment: but it should not have a height because main-content should should depend on the content of the 3 column

Comment: Huh. Somehow everybody got voted back to zero (big win) but me. Glad you got your issue resolved, though :)

Comment: I am flummoxed as to why I'm being downvoted. I'd just walk away except I'm new to this site and I'm not sure how it works exactly. As I see it, I provided a simple, working solution, albeit not the solution the OP was looking for. I thought downvoting was reserved for irrelevant, or non-useful answers? Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score -1):

It is a simple solution, add some content or set a height to the content element and you will see the background you want.

Comment: but it should not have a height because main-content should should depend on the content of the 3 column

Comment: yes but these guys are floating so there is "nothing" inside

Comment: Then use `min-height`

Comment: rather than using float to align them all, why not put them in a span tag? that way you will get rid of the float and will get your background like you wanted

Comment: I tried to put some content. Clearing a floating div is the solution. Thanks to C Travel. Thank you also to your comments. I don't know a lot of us got downvote

Comment: yeah C Travel suggested to clear the floats, I suggested to fully remove them and put span tags! I hate floats the make things difficult